# nonequalent on analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on $G$ to $G$ ($G$ is upper half plane)  and $f(i)=i$.

prove that

$Imw(|f(w)|^2 +1)<Imf(w)(|w|^2 +1)$.

my work:i think Schwarz Lemma is useful.

thanks for your help

Comment: Where to did the Schwarz lemma take you?

Comment: i think  Schwarz Lemma is useful for this question. if you have a good idea i thanks for this.

Comment: It probably is useful. What do you need to use the Schwarz lemma?

Comment: with other way i cant solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be smaller or equal in your inequality. In this case we can conclude like this. Let $H$ be the upper half plane and $D$ be the open unit disc. We have a biholomorphic map $\varphi\colon H\to D\,,\, z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}$. Let $g=\varphi f\varphi^{-1}$ - a holomorphic map from $D$ to $D$. Since $f(i)=i$ we have $g(0)=0$. Schwarz' Lemma gives that $|g(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z\in D$ or equivalent $\left|\frac{f(w)-i}{f(w)+i}\right|\leq\left|\frac{w-i}{w+i}\right|$ for all $w\in H$. If you take squares this gives you:
$$
\frac{|f(w)|^2+1-2\mathrm{Im}f(w)}{|f(w)|^2+1+2\mathrm{Im}(w)}\leq\frac{|w|^2+1-2\mathrm{Im}w}{|w|^2+1+2\mathrm{Im}w}
$$
for all $w\in H$.
If you now clear denominators and simplify both sides you get the desired inequality.